# Sub/Beta site to EESE

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I noticed recently that StackOverflow seems to have two sites of its own, Stack Overflow Meta and Careers 2.0.

I'm guessing this Careers 2.0 is just a beta of Stack Overflow.  Is there some reason we couldn't have another site along side EE-Meta?  Maybe something to do with recent press releases or new items and such?

**I guess the underlying question is how did the sub-beta site (such as careers 2.0) come into existence and could we do that?**

Comment: Careers 2.0 is a job recruitment service for mainly programming jobs. From what I gather it's the main revenue source for Stack Exchange which is why they don't have to go crazy with ads on the site.

Comment: Is there any reason we couldn't do something like that for Electrical Engineering?

Comment: I guess it would be a matter if they thought EE job placement was worthwhile. Stack Overflow has a much larger user base and I believe the service costs a fair bit for employers to use, it's more for full-time careers not "could someone prototype this for $5k" type listings. There are quite a few embedded jobs listed, and there's probably no reason an employer couldn't advertise an EE hardware job just they don't really target that market.

Comment: That makes sense

Answer (score 2):

Careers 2.0 is not particularly linked to SO.  It's invitation-only from Stack Exchange central.  I don't know the algorithms for how they choose people to invite, though.  I received one, but haven't chosen to participate.

We already have a meta site, and you're on it.

Some SE sites have their own blogs, but I don't know much about that.  It doesn't feel like that would work particularly well with EESE to me, but I can't really say why.

Comment: This pretty well sums it up. Just one note though is you can request an invite which I did not that I've used much. There was a question a while back about adding an EE account to Careers and I just checked and that person doesn't have any SE account with over 200 rep, so presumably the bar is relatively low and it's mainly to stop trolls / sockpuppets signing up.